# View is not shown before viewDidAppear called? When is the view shown?

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to do an animation -- visible to the user -- right after a view appears onscreen in iOS.  I would have expected I could put this in viewDidAppear; the docs make it sound like this will be called right after the view is visible.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case -- viewDidAppear is being called before the view is actually visible. The view is created programmatically, not from nib. Here's an abstracted example:

```
sampleviewcontroller.m
@implementation sampleViewController
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {

    // setup a generic view 
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}    

// View should be shown by now?
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    return; // set breakpoint here, but view is NOT visible in simulator at this point
}
```

This creates a plain blue view.  However, if I set a breakpoint at the return line in viewDidAppear, that blue view is NOT visible when the breakpoint is reached.  It becomes visible sometime later.

Is this expected?  When will the view actually become visible to the user?  App Delegate code is stock pregen stuff:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I'm using an older SDK (on Snow Leopard) if that matters...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's all about application loops, you won't be able to see the view while you're on that breakpoint. It's true, that viewDidAppear is called when the view is visible, but not when you use it with code brakpoints.

Comment: 100% right. viewDidAppear is called when [self.window.rootView addSubview:newVC.view] is called. drawing hasnt happened at that point though (except if it appeared animated of course)

Answer (score 1):

As user1851930 said, the run loop is 'stopped' with your breakpoint and drawing didnt happen yet. 
if you need that to happen once, delay animation by 0.0f (one iteration of the loop)

use:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedAppear) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
}

- (void)delayedAppear {
    //view has been drawn 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks for the help; I don't think I would have reached this conclusion on my own.  Is this a common trick?  Just thinking of those games I've played that show a splash screen or some such ... do they use a similar method to ensure the splash is visible for some period of time?

Comment: Method should apparently be named `viewIsJustAboutTo_WaitForIt__WaitForIt__Appear:`